# "written in skim milk" means cheesy, soppy writing?

Tags: idioms

I just read [Raymond Chandler's letter to Hitchcock](http://www.openculture.com/2013/08/raymond-chandler-denounces-hitchcocks-strangers-on-a-train.html) (which is brilliantly written); Chandler is ranting about the script for a film, pretty much calling the final script rubbish, and this is where I came across this sentence:

> But if you wanted something written in skim milk, why on earth did you bother to come to me in the first place?

I understand the meaning of the whole text, and get the gist of the quoted sentence, but never ever before I read this particular figure-of-speech. Is it an established one? My google search only returned dairy related stuff. Is it the invention of Chandler to express cheesy, soppy, schmaltzy writing?

Comment: [Skim milk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skimmed_milk) is milk with all the cream removed; essentially, it's watered-down, weak milk.  I think Chandler is saying "if you wanted something weak and without character..."  It is not an established figure of speech as far as I know, though.

Comment: Oh wow, yes, now that makes sense. Because basically he complains about the final script and the characters in it being "watered down".

Comment: I am going to promote my comment to an answer, since it seems to have garnered some support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Skim milk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skimmed_milk) is milk with all the cream removed, which gives it a watered-down, weak flavor.  Chandler is essentially saying, "If you wanted something weak and without character, why did you ask me to write for you?" [Raymond Chandler](http://www.goodreads.com/author/show/1377.Raymond_Chandler) was known as a founder of the "[hard-boiled](http://www.britannica.com/art/hard-boiled-fiction)" school of detective fiction, which is usually tough, earthy, and violent, so he would not be a natural choice if you wanted something bland and mild!

I have never seen the exact analogy "writing in skim milk", but "skim milk" is sometimes used as an analogy for "a weak or false version of the real thing".  For example, Supreme Court Justice Ruth Bader Ginsburg once said that a law created two different kinds of marriage and one of them was a "[skim milk marriage](http://www.slate.com/blogs/the_slatest/2013/03/27/ginsburg_s_doma_milk_quote_ruth_bader_ginsburg_says_law_creates_two_tiered.html)", meaning that it wasn't really real.  In another usage, some Confederate soldiers during the US Civil War called their opponents "[Skim Milk Yankees](https://books.google.com/books?id=alfD8DZ9wzIC&lpg=PR11&ots=8sbsKIjAw_&dq=skim%20milk%20analogy&pg=PA22#v=snippet&q=pinned%20on%20them%20by%20their%20foes&f=false)", implying that they were weak.

Answer (score 0):

First thought - **invisible ink**.

Using milk as ink is a well known way to write hidden messages (perhaps better known in 1950 when the letter was written).  The process is to write using milk as ink, allow it dry, then reveal the message at a later time by heating the paper with a light bulb or other mild heat source. It works with whole milk, but less well with skim milk.

Since Chandler was a mystery writer, perhaps he was making this kind of reference.

The final script bore so little resemblance to the Chandler's original that perhaps the implication was far beyond "watered-down".  The writing could just as well have been submitted as blank paper for anyone to write anything they chose as a revision.  Of course, suggesting skim-milk makes it even more unlikely that anyone had made the "revision" based on the original.